# SetNamedSecurityInfo for a 64Bit registry key from a 32Bit Process

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, registry

I am trying to use SetNamedSecurityInfo from a 32Bit application to set ACLs for a 64Bit registry key. Due to SetNamedSecurityInfo limitation that has only KEY_WOW64_32KEY flag this is not possible.

**Copy paste from some post on MSDN:**
No way to access 64-bit registry keys in WOW64

Note: When getting or setting the ACLs in the registry using SetNamedSecurityInfo or GetNamedSecurityInfo there is no way to access the 64-bit registry keys from a 32-bit DLL or EXE. A new SE_OBJECT_TYPE named SE_REGISTRY_WOW64_64KEY is needed that sets KEY_WOW64_64KEY in NTMARTA.DLL.

This means, for example, there is no way to create a 32/64bit agnostic SETUP.EXE that can adjust registry security settings during an installation. The workaround is to create a 64-bit DLL or EXE and distribute bot

**My Question:**
There is any workaround to solve this problem without creating a 64Bit application?

Comment: You've already got the answer which is to stop running your code in the WOW64 emulator. If there is a way it will involve the native API.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use `SetSecurityInfo` ?  That's the obvious solution ...

Comment: It seems SetSecurityInfo opens a new handle to the key that is passed in (RegOpenKeyEx(key, NULL, ...)), presumably to attain the necessary access rights. Trouble is, if you open a new handle to a 64-bit key without specifying the KEY_WOW64_64KEY flag again, you get back a handle to the 32-bit key. It seems that there is no solution for my problem. The only one is to have a 64 bit application. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use SetSecurityInfo instead:

```
HKEY hSecKey;
if( RegOpenKeyEx( hHive, Subkey.c_str(), 0, ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hSecKey ) != ERROR_SUCCESS ) 
    return;

SetSecurityInfo(hSecKey, SE_REGISTRY_KEY, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, &pDacl, NULL);
```

You have to obtain SE_SECURITY_NAME privilege first to open a key with ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY.

Comment: You should use `READ_CONTROL` rather than `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY`.  That way, you don't need `SE_SECURITY_NAME`.  The `ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY` right is for accessing the auditing rules ACL, known as the SACL; `READ_CONTROL` is for accessing the access control rules, known as the DACL.  In this case you're reading the DACL.

Comment: Also, according to the OP, SetSecurityInfo doesn't work because it reopens the key.  I haven't verified this myself.